# What is the difference between minimum nominator bonding amount and minimum active bond?

Tags: staking

In the [Polkadot Staking Dashboard](https://staking.polkadot.network) it says:

[image]

But then under [Nominate](https://staking.polkadot.network/#/nominate) it specifies the minimum active bond as 171.832 DOTs:

[image]

What is the difference between the 10 DOT minimum and the minimum active bond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[minimum nominator bond](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1802a115e8480fd7a4654d45c85b58c2189c508a/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L288-L290) is the balance needs at least to be able to start nominating. This one being configured at runtime level.

Whereas minimum active bond refers to, based on the actual state of the whole nominations, how much stake you will need to nominate to start seeing rewards.
As per that page description:

> The minimum active bond statistic is the minimum DOT being bonded by a nominator for the current era.

Nomination pools address this to offer an "easier" experience.

Some more concrete details from [proposal#1224](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/post/1224)

> First, let’s recap on the current status quo: Currently, nominators
> can freely set their intention to nominate in Polkadot, as long as
> they meet two limits: a minimum of 10 DOTs is staked, and a maximum of
> 50_000 nominators is not filled. This creates a nomination market,
> where in every era, the top 22_500 nominators from this open market
> are chosen to participate in the election process, and possibly
> receive staking rewards (if other conditions like over-subscription
> are not met).
>
> ```
> This is a complicated and involved process. Nomination pools are exactly here to combat this and provide a simpler experience for
> ```
>
> DOT-holders to participate in staking.
>
> Based on this, let’s cluster Polkadot nominators into two groups:
> active (in the top 22500), and waiting. The main concern at this point
> is to
>
> 1. Encourage all existing waiting nominators to join pools. This is mainly a task for the Wallet/UI development ecosystem, and is beyond
>    the scope of this discussion.
> 2. Prevent too many waiting nominators to be created. The reason being that I speculate that most of these nominators have erroneously
>    in the waiting queue, and prefer joining pools instead.